# sed command to replace char at a specific byte position

Tags: linux

I am having two files say test1 & test2 having a difference at some random position.So i want to search for char position that differ in test1  from test 2 & want to replace that with * in test 1 . But the constraint is without knowing the char by just knowing the position of char.
So i have tried to use the cmp -b to get the byte position that differ but cant get something in sed or any where that can replace char at a byte position or something in compare that will give line no. as well as char position in line that differ. So any help (the main constraint is that cant replace with char value as don't want that change at other places in file want change only at that position). sed first occurrence replacement will also not work as first occurence may be before the differ position.

Comment: Your question is terribly unclear, I just cannot figure out what you are after.  I believe it is a valid question, since you present a problem and try to present how you attempted to solve it.  It is just a little fuzzy what the actual intent is.  Can you provide an example of two files (1-2 lines of text) and the result you are after?

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to write some byte at some offset without file truncation, maybe dd will help?

Setup:

```
$ cat f1
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
$ cat f2
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaa
```

Script:

```
if ! CMPOUT=`cmp -b f1 f2`; then
    POS=`echo "$CMPOUT" | sed -r 's/^.*: byte ([0-9]+),.*$/\1/'`
    echo -n '*' | dd of=f2 seek="$((POS-1))" bs=1 count=1 conv=notrunc
fi
```

Result:

```
$ cat f2 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa*aaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer  will try & let u know, this is what i want , nicely put in example , but my file is of more than a line& difference can be in any line , file can be in MB also , will it work  for that size of file.

Comment: @Mahi.G: just try it out, I think it will work for just about anything, including binary files, as long as `cmp` output is the one expected.

Comment: Thanks , what if i want to just add * before b in file 2 using dd as below -

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa*baaaaaaaaa

Comment: @Mahi.G: Well, just use `seek="$((POS-2))"`

Comment: I mean adding * before b in to file without replacing anything so that file size will increase by 1 byte